# My corona sdk project won't build properly on Android

Tags: java, android, coronasdk, jarsigner

I have posted about this problem on the Corona forums, but was not able to get an answer there.

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/29712-android-failure-install-parse-failed-certificate-encoding/

Basically the problem is that my project runs fine in the simulator, but when I try to build for Android and transfer the apk, I get an error message saying "The application could not be installed." This problem only occurs on my mac. When I build with a Windows 8 virtual machine, it builds fine and runs on my Nexus 7. Please check the link to the forum for some of the troubleshooting I have already done.

Notes:

- I am using Java 6, not 7
- Currently using the latest public build of Corona, but the problem has happened on earlier builds
- I can successfully build an Android app using the JDK
- I have a 13-inch, Mid 2010 Macbook Pro
- Same problem happens on my brother's Macbook Pro bought 2 years earlier

Comment: Are you getting any messages from the devices console log?  Can you do an "adb logcat" with the device tethered and see why its giving you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed now, I'm not sure if it was a newer version of Corona or Java, or if we changed something in our code.